# Where I can find example how prove red black tree?

Tags: proof-techniques, binary-trees, induction

I need prove that any red-black tree with at least two elements obtained through the insertion algorithm has at least one red node.
For this, I need use Induction.

I don't understand how apply induction. (((

Answer (score 2):

Here is the obvious thing to try:

1. Prove that if you apply the insertion algorithm twice on an empty tree, then the resulting red-black tree has a red node (this also follows from the invariants of red-black trees).
2. Prove that if a red-black tree has a red node and you insert an element using the insertion algorithm, then the result red-black tree has a red node.

I don't know if this scheme works, but it's the most immediate way to apply induction.